# Adding New Page in GridView in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Basically I am trying to make Flutter Dashboard in which I planned to import GridView Dashboard, but Unfortunately I am Facing error like

```
Compiler message:
lib/screens/grid_dashboard.dart:13:9: Error: Getter not found: 'context'.
        context,
        ^^^^^^^
```

My issue is like when I click item1 it needs to redirect a new page, a new page goes with fresh page> steps with many features

I have added some code and modified several parts of it, also getting error in context

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:testapp/screens/create_shipment.dart';

class GridDashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  Items item1 = new Items(
    title: 'Create Shipment',
    subtitle: 'shipment starts here',
    img: 'assets/images/booking.png',
    icon: Icon(Icons.local_shipping),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => CreateShipment(),
        ),
      );},
  );
  Items item2 = new Items(
    title: 'Pre Booking Status',
    subtitle: 'booking status updation',
    img: 'assets/images/prebooking.png',
  );
  Items item3 = new Items(
    title: 'Booking Status',
    subtitle: 'confirmed order update',
    img: 'assets/images/delivery.png',
  );
  Items item4 = new Items(
    title: 'My Wallet',
    subtitle: 'wallet history',
    img: 'assets/images/wallet.png',
  );
  Items item5 = new Items(
    title: 'Add Promocode',
    subtitle: 'validate ur promocode',
    img: 'assets/images/coupon.png',
  );
  Items item6 = new Items(
    title: 'Invoices',
    subtitle: 'all ur invoices',
    img: 'assets/images/invoice.png',
  );

//  static BuildContext context;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Items> myList = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6];
    var color = 0xfffafafa;
    return Flexible(
        child: GridView.count(
            childAspectRatio: 1.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 16),
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 18,
            mainAxisSpacing: 18,
            children: myList.map((data) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(color),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(
                      data.img,
                      width: 42,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      data.title,
                      style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black87,
                          fontSize: 15,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      data.subtitle,
                      style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black87,
                          fontSize: 11,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
//                    GestureDetector(
//                      onTap: data.onPressed,
//                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }).toList()));
  }
}

class Items {
  String title;
  String subtitle;
  String img;
  Widget icon;
  final Function onPressed;
  Items({this.title, this.subtitle, this.icon, this.img, this.onPressed});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BuildContext only exists inside Widget build(BuildContext context) method, you cant access it from outside.

Comment: for that what shall i do please guide it

Comment: https://gist.github.com/SempaiEcchi/05d68026bed71a9f690847c9b6b7787f

Comment: Thanks for Help but it throws an another error https://gist.github.com/mgr2012/a08720338e773968971a58abbdbe8f05

Comment: Thanks finally I wrapped with Expanded Widget I Solve this issue, Thanks